# PHP: Upload a Pdf to SQL Database

Tags: php, sql, pdf, file-upload

Hi so I am wondering where to start on uploading a pdf to a sql database. I am trying to make it so that a user can upload a file and then hit submit and that file is stored in a cell on a sql database. Is this the correct way to solve this problem? I do not need to parse the pdf at all, I just need to be able to upload it and pull it back out of the database. Thank you!

Comment: the best way is to upload the file on your server and store the file name on the database

Comment: Do you have a database yet? If so, how did you organize it i.e. what is the schema?

Comment: You really want to store whole PDF within database? or just store path of the pdf in one cell & access the pdf in your application using that path?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the PDF on the server or in a database.
If you need it to be stored in a database, use the following:

```
$fileAsString = base64_encode(file_get_contents('PDF.pdf'));
//now store $fileAsString in your database cell
```

When you need to read it again, you use base64_decode();

Comment: So how would the user go about uploading the file, for instance if they had a pdf on their desktop. I would just use a form to create the pointer to the pdf and then when they selected attach, then I would run the sql query?

Comment: You would upload the file as usual. PHP will create a temporary file for you, which you could read into the base64_encode() function, then take that string and save it to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to store pdf (as BLOB) in the database, (Assuming MySQL functions are being used to interface with the database) You could do something like this:

```
$store_pdf =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents('/pdf/file/path.pdf'))."')");
```

Note:

Storing BLOBs in databases is generally not considered.  A better approach would be to move the file somewhere in the filesystem and store the path to the file in the database instead of the file itself.

Eg.

```
$path_to_pdf='/pdf/file/path.pdf';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (pdf_path) VALUES ('$path_to_pdf')");
```

& Access pdf file after fetching the path from the table.

```
<?php 
$query=mysql_query("SELECT pdf_path FROM table");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $result['pdf_path']; ?>">Download PDF</a>
```

Note that the mysql extension is now deprecated and will be removed sometime in the future. You could use PDO functions instead. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: So how would the user go about uploading the file, for instance if they had a pdf on their desktop. I would just use a form to create the pointer to the pdf and then when they selected attach, then I would run the sql query?

Comment: @visualbasicNoob9000 If you're storing pdf content within DB, you don't need to upload the file. You just read the file contents & store it in the field. But it's not recommended instead just upload the file & store only the path within DB table field (Yeah..Running the SQL Query)